# Oracle APEX link to foreign key entries in object browser

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way in Oracle APEX object browser (for tables) to look at a row in a child table and drill down to the entry of the parent table that is referred by a foreign key?

For instance, let's say I have a Job Applications table which has a foreign key to an Applicant table (through a UIDAPPLICANT field). Is there a way to make the UIDAPPLICANT field in row 1 of Job Applications (when I am viewing this table in Object Browser) have a **link** to the row in Applicant that has the same UIDAPPLICANT? I am interested not just in the UID of the applicant but also, say, her highest level of education which could be stored in the Applicant table. I would like to go to her entry of the Applicant table without having to memorize her UID and going to the Applicant table.

Comment: You mean like a tree?

Comment: Not quite a tree, but just a link that takes me to the lookup table's entry